# Android Paging3 not receiving error state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-paging-3, android-diffutils

I'm using paging3. My `RemoteMediator` returns Result.Error from catch:

```
catch (e: Exception) {
            return MediatorResult.Error(handler.getError(e))
        }
```

Inside fragment I'm listening for state changes:

```
 adapter.addLoadStateListener { loadState ->
// here some code
}
```

The problem is that I am not getting `LoadState.Error` despite what the RemoteMediator returned `MediatorResult.Error`. Instead of an `LoadState.Error`I get `LoadState.NotLoading` .I get the rest of the states correctly.

Why might this be happening? Please help me

Answer (score 1):

I might be too late to answer, but since I experienced the same problem I will left my experience for others that might suffer the same case.

When I tried to get error by using code like, `if(loadState.refresh is LoadState.Error)`, I wasn't able to get error. So like the code below, I modified my code.

```
loadStateListener = { loadState ->
    when {
        loadState.prepend is LoadState.Error -> {
           loadState.prepend as LoadState.Error
        }
        loadState.append is LoadState.Error -> {
            loadState.append as LoadState.Error
        }
        loadState.refresh is LoadState.Error -> {
            loadState.refresh as LoadState.Error
        }
        else -> {
            null
        }
    }
```

Try checking for all load state type. In my case, when Network exception happens in the middle of scrolling, and `loadState type` was `append` and error was also triggered from there.

Hope my answer can be helpful for others.